# Forking with Pipes

Tags: c, process, pipe, unix

I have tried to do fork() and piping in main and it works perfectly fine but when I try to implement it in a function for some reason I don't get any output, this is my code:

```
void cmd(int **pipefd,int count,int type, int last);    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int pipefd[3][2];
int i, total_cmds = 3,count = 0;
int in = 1;

for(i = 0; i < total_cmds;i++){
 pipe(pipefd[count++]);
 cmd(pipefd,count,i,0);    
}

 /*Last Command*/
 cmd(pipefd,count,i,1);    

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void cmd(int **pipefd,int count,int type, int last){    
    int child_pid,i,i2;

     if ((child_pid = fork()) == 0) {

            if(count == 1){
               dup2(pipefd[count-1][1],1); /*first command*/
            }
            else if(last!=1){
               dup2(pipefd[count - 2][0],0); /*middle commands*/
               dup2(pipefd[count - 1][1],1);
            }
            else if(last == 1){
               dup2(pipefd[count - 1][0],0); /*last command*/
            }


            for(i = 0; i < count;i++){/*close pipes*/
            for(i2 = 0; i2 < 2;i2++){
               close(pipefd[i][i2]);
            }}



            if(type == 0){
                execlp("ls","ls","-al",NULL);
            }
            else if(type == 1){
                execlp("grep","grep",".bak",NULL);
            }
            else if(type==2){
                               execl("/usr/bin/wc","wc",NULL);
            }
            else if(type ==3){
                         execl("/usr/bin/wc","wc","-l",NULL);
           }
            perror("exec");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (child_pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I checked the file descriptors and it is opening the right ones, not sure what the problem
could be..

Edit: I Fixed the problem but I'm having child processes, which way would be the best to wait for the child , while(wait(NULL)!=-1); but that hangs

Comment: You can't pass `pipefd[3][2]` (a conventional two-dimensional array) as `int**` see http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc3.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `pipefd` is not an `int**`, it's an `int[3][2]`, so when you pass it to `cmd`, you get garbage.  Your compiler *should* be giving you a warning on each call to `cmd()`, such as something like this:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'cmd' from incompatible pointer type
```

If not, turn up your warning level.

It's true that arrays decay into pointers to their first elements, so you can pass a 1-D array to a function expecting a pointer, but **that's only true for the first dimension of arrays**.  In particular, a 2D array does **not** decay into a pointer to a pointer.  It decays at the first level only, so `pipefd` can decay into the type `int (*)[2]`, which is read as "pointer to array 2 of `int`"

So, the correct way to write `cmd` is this:

```
void cmd(int (*pipefd)[2],int count,int type, int last)
```

Comment: Ahh Okay That solved some of the problem but in thhis method would be the best way to kill the child processes